# object that doesn't show up on list of... objects

Tags: permissions, customsetting

I have this object called DateTimeSetter:

- Label **DateTimeSetter**
- Object Name **DateTimeSetter**
- API Name **DateTimeSetter__c**
- Setting Type **Hierarchy**
- Visibility **Public**
- Description **(blank)**
- Namespace Prefix **(blank)**
- Created Date **2/29/2016 1:05 PM**
- Last Modified Date **2/29/2016 1:05 PM**

From any profile other than system admin, I can not save data that uses this object.

From the profiles I have, I can't find this object. The setting Type option is Grey out showing only the "Hierarchy" option making impossible to change this setting (as far as I know).

How can I do to enable access to this object from profiles other than admin?

Comment: I removed the DateTime tag, because that tag is meant for working with the Salesforce-provided `DateTime` class. Also, this appears to be regarding a Custom Setting (rather than a custom sObject).

Comment: Where are you trying to access it? [You need `Customize Application` to modify any `Custom Setting` record](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_about.htm). It's a pretty heavy permission. Probably better to build a custom UI...

Comment: Daniel Hoechst has a solution to allow any user to edit a custom setting using a visualforce page and JavaScript remoting.  Not something i could do but maybe helpful for you...http://www.verticalcoder.com/2014/07/25/allowing-any-user-to-edit-custom-settings/